# How to query for values that are non text string

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to query a table given these conditions, where the values contain integers but not text strings my query looks like this currently

```
select column
from table
where column  ~ '^[0-9]'
```

This does a decent job and gets most of my use cases but I am still running into situations where I get values where there are numbers and text such as '50first' 
Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Is it possible that the two can be interspersed, like `50first20second30`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only integers, then the correct regular expression is:

```
select column
from table
where column ~ '^[0-9]+$'
```

Your code checks that the column *starts* with a digit.  The above guarantees that the column consists only of digits from the beginning to the end -- and has at least one of them.

Comment: `$` mean after a chain of number you string end so `50first` doesnt happen

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work fine.

```
select column from table where upper(column) = lower(column);
```